# Binding observableArray to C# list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have the following simpified ViewModel in C#

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public IList<IdAndNameModel> AvailableTags { get; set; }
    public IList<IdAndNameModel> SearchTags { get; set; }
}
```

and this in JavaScript:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.allTags = ko.observableArray();
    self.searchTags = ko.observableArray();

    // stuff to fill the searchTags
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.allTags(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.AvailableTags)));
```

Now I want to bind the JavaScript property to the `SearchModel`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SearchTags, new { data_bind = "value: searchTags" })
```

Here is the snippet how the data is submitted to the controller:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    var form = $('#criteriaForm');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            // unimportant binding stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately the length of the list is always 0. I bet the reason is the initialisation of the availabaleTags array (`@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.AvailableTags))`). I am right? If I change the type from list to string then I can see that the binding is generally working.

Is there a way to bind lists in that way?

Comment: When and how do you check the length of the list? So how do you know that the length of the list is always 0?

Comment: Controller side, after submitting.

Comment: ok, and how do you submit your data? With using a regular form tag and a submit button or with AJAX?

Comment: I submit the data via an JavaScript-AJAX-call (not with the .Net functionality!). The data comes from here: `data: form.serialize()`

Comment: Then the `form.serialize()` is your problem because it is not correctly serializes your array in the form how ASP.NET would accept it. Please post your ajax code! By the way if you have your viewmodel bacause of KO why don't you send the data from that directly in your ajax call?

Comment: @nemesv: thanks for your hints so far. I updated my initial post. To your second suggestion: I didn't know that this is possible. But that would mean that I need to have a identical JavaScript copy of my C#-model? So far I have a lot more properties in my C#-model -> properties that don't need to be updated during filling the form.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would change the `$.ajax` call to look more like this:

```
$.ajax(form.attr('action'), {
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'AvailableTags': viewModel.allTags(),
        'SearchTags': viewModel.searchTags()
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        //Do your thang
    }
});
```

Then you controller will have a method that looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(SearchViewModel searchViewModel) {
    //Stuffy stuff, best stuff on earth
}
```

Last suggestion would be to put the

```
viewModel.allTags(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.AvailableTags)));
```

before the

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont want to send them separately you might want to try the following.knockout has this problem with the C# list, so while interacting with C# side you'd need to convert it back.

`data: JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(yourobject))`